# How can I select rows in an SQL table by using multiple substrings of a single column value?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am using Oracle SQL Developer to query a database of cases, and I need to use three different identifiers to select the correct row for each case; however, my problem is that two of the identifiers are contained in the same text string, and I can’t figure out how to parse them to use in the query.

In the following table, the identifiers I need to use are:

1. **ID-1**, characters 3–6 in the "Case" column (e.g., "1001"),
2. **ID-2**, characters 8–9 in the "Case" column (e.g., "01") *when they appear* (treated as "00" if they don't appear), and
3. **ID-3**, the value in the "Sequence" column (e.g., "672").

#### Source Table

| Case | Sequence | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA1001 | 672 | 73 | 195 |
| AA1001 | 711 | 73 | 185 |
| AA1001-01 | 680 | 73 | 185 |
| AA1001-02 | 685 | 72 | 185 |
| AA1001-02 | 699 | 72 | 182 |
| AB1002 | 676 | 51 | 36 |
| AB1002-01 | 701 | 48 | 39 |
| AB1002-01 | 719 | 48 | 35 |
| AB1002-02 | 707 | 51 | 38 |
| AA1003 | 655 | 122 | 416 |
| AA1003 | 683 | 113 | 416 |

I want to return one row for each unique ID-1, such that *first* the greatest value for ID-2 is selected, and *then* the greatest value for ID-3 *in that subset* is chosen; so, the query should return only the following three rows from the table above.

#### Result Table

| Case | Sequence | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA1001-02 | 699 | 72 | 182 |
| AB1002-02 | 707 | 51 | 38 |
| AA1003 | 683 | 113 | 416 |

I've tried taking the maximum for ID-2 using the following, but it only returns the rows where ID-2 equals "02".

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE SUBSTR(Case,3,4) in ('1001','1002','1003') 
and SUBSTR(Case,8,2) = (SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(Case,8,2)) 
FROM table 
WHERE SUBSTR(Case,3,4) in ('1001','1002','1003'))
```

(The easiest answer is probably just to add a column for ID-2; however, the source database is strictly read-only, so I can't make that sort of change.)

Comment: Create your ID columns using sbstr in a CTE then select from your CTE.

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column you just need to handle the substrings.

Comment: Obviously, in your attempt you aren't even considering the third ID - you are selecting row(s) with highest `ID-2` for each `ID-1`, but you are not further selecting just the row with the highest `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: Something else is odd though - you are only looking at the numeric part like 1001 and 1002. Don't the first two characters matter? Can't you have cases like AA1005-xx and AB1005-xx? (Same ID-1 of 1005, but the first two letters are **different**?) If this can happen, is your handling correct - you must MIX THEM TOGETHER?

Comment: @mathguy, I figured it was a waste of time to try to get the maximum Sequence when I couldn't yet find the highest ID-2.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, @mathguy, the first two characters are irrelevant for my purposes; AA1005 and AB1005 cannot both appear in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, you can use the `match_recognize` clause:

```
select case, sequence, value1, value2
from   (
         select t.*, substr(case, 3, 4) as id_1, substr(case, 8, 2) as id_2
         from   table_name t
       )
match_recognize(
  partition by id_1
  order     by id_2 desc nulls last, sequence desc nulls last
  all rows per match
  pattern   (^ x)
  define    x as null is null
);


CASE        SEQUENCE     VALUE1     VALUE2
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------
AA1001-02        699         72        182
AB1002-02        707         51         38
AA1003           683        113        416
```

Comment: Thank you; `match_recognize` is new to me, so this is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function and find the `SUBSTR`ings to partition/order by:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY
             SUBSTR(Case, 3, 4)
           ORDER BY
             COALESCE(SUBSTR(Case, 8, 2), '00') DESC,
             Sequence DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Case, Sequence, Value1, Value2 ) AS
SELECT 'AA1001',    672,  73, 195 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1001',    711,  73, 185 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1001-01', 680,  73, 185 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1001-02', 685,  72, 185 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1001-02', 699,  72, 182 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AB1002',    676,  51,  36 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AB1002-01', 701,  48,  39 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AB1002-01', 719,  48,  35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AB1002-02', 707,  51,  38 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1003',    655, 122, 416 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1003',    683, 113, 416 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CASE | SEQUENCE | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | RN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | AA1001-02 | 699 | 72 | 182 | 1 |
> | AB1002-02 | 707 | 51 | 38 | 1 |
> | AA1003 | 683 | 113 | 416 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b69733e3c4c0ab95ef130daddff42ebd)*

Comment: Or, instead of coalescing `'00'` when `ID-2` is missing, simply order by `ID-2 desc NULLS LAST`. Allow `ID-2` to be `NULL` even for ordering, just handle as needed.

Comment: Thank you for this; it works perfectly, but the other answer returns results about twice as fast for me.